# How to find pair of subarrays with maximal sum

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

Given an array of integers, I can find the maximal subarray sum using [Kadane's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem). In code this looks like:

```
def kadane(arr, n):
    # initialize subarray_sum, max_subarray_sum and
    subarray_sum = 0
    max_subarray_sum = np.int32(-2**31)
    # Just some initial value to check
    # for all negative values case
    finish = -1

    # local variable
    local_start = 0

    for i in range(n):
        subarray_sum += arr[i]
        if subarray_sum < 0:
            subarray_sum = 0
            local_start = i + 1
        elif subarray_sum > max_subarray_sum:
            max_subarray_sum = subarray_sum
            start = local_start
            finish = i

    # There is at-least one
    # non-negative number
    if finish != -1:
        return max_subarray_sum, start, finish

    # Special Case: When all numbers in arr[] are negative
    max_subarray_sum = arr[0]
    start = finish = 0
    # Find the maximum element in array
    for i in range(1, n):
        if arr[i] > max_subarray_sum:
            max_subarray_sum = arr[i]
            start = finish = i
    return max_subarray_sum, start, finish
```

This is fast and works well. However, I would like to find a pair of subarrays with maximal sum.   Take this example input.

```
arr = [3, 3, 3, -8, 3, 3, 3]
```

The maximal subarray is the entire array with sum 10. But if I am allowed to take two subarrays they can be [3, 3, 3] and [3, 3, 3] which has sum 18.

Is there a fast algorithm to compute the maximal pair of subarrays? I am assuming the two subarrays will not overlap.

Comment: "_[3, 3, 3] and [3, 3, 3] which has sum 18_". . . how ?

Comment: So the subarrays must be contiguous and non-overlapping? What is the motivation for the question? Is it a self imposed exercise, coding challenge, or something else?

Comment: @SimonGoater Overlapping doesn't make sense here unless you double count. I learned kadane and this is a natural extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kadane's algorithm is used to find the maximal subarray sum in an array of integers. However, to find the maximal pair of non-overlapping subarrays with maximal sum, a different approach is needed. One way to solve this is by using the concept of prefix and suffix sums. Here's a high-level overview of the algorithm:

- Compute the prefix sum and suffix sum arrays for the given array.
- Use Kadane's algorithm to find the maximum sum subarray in the prefix sum array, which gives the maximal subarray ending at each position.
- Use Kadane's algorithm in reverse to find the maximum sum subarray in the suffix sum array, which gives the maximal subarray starting at each position.
- Iterate through the array and find the pair of non-overlapping subarrays with maximal sum by combining the results from steps 2 and 3.

This approach has a time complexity of O(n) (and space complexity of O(n)) and can efficiently find the maximal pair of subarrays with maximal sum, where n is the size of the input array.

```
def max_subarray(arr, rev=False):
    best_sum = [(arr[0], 0, 0)]
    current_sum = (arr[0], 0, 0)
    for j in range(1, len(arr)):
        current_sum = max(
            (arr[j], j, j),
            (current_sum[0] + arr[j], current_sum[1], j)
        )
        best_sum.append(max(best_sum[-1], current_sum))
    return [
        (t[0], len(arr) - t[2] - 1, len(arr) - t[1] - 1)
        for t in reversed(best_sum)
    ] if rev else best_sum


def max_pair_subarray(arr):
    max_sub = max_subarray(arr)
    max_sub_rev = max_subarray(list(reversed(arr)), rev=True)
    max_sum = (max_sub[0][0] + max_sub_rev[1][0], max_sub[0], max_sub_rev[1])
    for j in range(1, len(arr) - 2):
        max_sum = max(
            max_sum,
            (max_sub[j][0] + max_sub_rev[j + 1][0], max_sub[j], max_sub_rev[j + 1]),
        )
    return (
        max_sum[0],
        (max_sum[1][1], max_sum[1][2]),
        (max_sum[2][1], max_sum[2][2]),
    )

max_sum, (start_idx_1, end_idx_1), (start_idx_2, end_idx_2) = max_pair_subarray(arr)
```

Comment: I think this is double counting in the sense that it sometimes reports overlapping subarrays and then adds the sums of each.

Comment: This gives 25 for arr = [3,3,3,-1, 3,3,3] but the maximal score is 18.

Comment: Thank  you so much for this. I am not sure why the other answer, based on similar ideas, gives the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

Modified version here, the idea is to keep track of the maximum subarray sum ending at each position and the maximum subarray sum starting at each position. By iterating through the array, you can find the two non-overlapping subarrays with maximal sum.

code:

```
import numpy as np

def max_subarray_pair(arr, n):
    max_ending_here = np.zeros(n)
    max_starting_here = np.zeros(n)

    # Calculate maximum subarray sum ending at each position
    max_ending_here[0] = arr[0]
    for i in range(1, n):
        max_ending_here[i] = max(arr[i], max_ending_here[i - 1] + arr[i])

    # Calculate maximum subarray sum starting at each position
    max_starting_here[n - 1] = arr[n - 1]
    for i in range(n - 2, -1, -1):
        max_starting_here[i] = max(arr[i], max_starting_here[i + 1] + arr[i])

    # Find the position where the sum of ending and starting subarrays is maximized
    max_sum = np.int32(-2**31)
    pos = -1
    for i in range(n - 1):
        if max_ending_here[i] + max_starting_here[i + 1] > max_sum:
            max_sum = max_ending_here[i] + max_starting_here[i + 1]
            pos = i

    # Calculate the indices for the two non-overlapping subarrays
    start1, finish1 = kadane_helper(arr[:pos + 1])
    start2, finish2 = kadane_helper(arr[pos + 1:])

    finish2 += pos + 1  # Adjust the index for the second subarray

    return max_sum, start1, finish1, start2, finish2

def kadane_helper(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    subarray_sum = 0
    max_subarray_sum = np.int32(-2**31)
    local_start = 0
    start = finish = -1

    for i in range(n):
        subarray_sum += arr[i]
        if subarray_sum < 0:
            subarray_sum = 0
            local_start = i + 1
        elif subarray_sum > max_subarray_sum:
            max_subarray_sum = subarray_sum
            start = local_start
            finish = i

    if finish != -1:
        return start, finish
    else:
        max_subarray_sum = arr[0]
        start = finish = 0
        for i in range(1, n):
            if arr[i] > max_subarray_sum:
                max_subarray_sum = arr[i]
                start = finish = i
        return start, finish
```

## Example usage:

arr = [3, 3, 3, -8, 3, 3, 3]

result = max_subarray_pair(arr, len(arr))

print("Maximal Subarray Pair:", result[1:])

This modified code calculates the maximum subarray sum ending and starting at each position and then finds the position where their sum is maximized. Finally, it uses the original kadane_helper function to find the two non-overlapping subarrays.

Comment: I get 10 when arr= [3,3,3,-8, 3,3,3] but the maximal score is 18.